# Can I force PHP implode function to print quotes around string values?

Tags: javascript, php

```
$axisLabel = array(
    "HI",
    "MOM"
);
echo implode(',', $axisLabel);
```

Prints:

```
HI,MOM
```

I want

```
"HI", "MOM"
```

I need quotes values for insertion of values into JavaScript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass array to javascript you should use `json_encode()` function:

```
echo json_encode($axisLabel);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I always do

```
echo '"'.implode('","', $axisLabel).'"';
```

Comment: Good luck if `$axisLabel` contains characters like `"` or `\ ` though... rolling your own encoding is a bad idea, and `json_encode` exists for a reason.

Comment: that's what I originally did and it seemed to work -> `['"' . <?php echo implode('", "', $axisLabel); ?> . '"']` but it seemed like there's gotta be something clever-er

Comment: @Dennis I would use json_encode as everyone suggested. Depends on your need and input data though